# trying to retrieve image from parse.com but getting error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

```
   func loadImages() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "CollegeCover")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            let imageObjects = objects! as [PFObject]

            for object in objects! {

                let thumbNail = object["image"] as! PFFile


                thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects, error) -> Void in

                    if (error == nil) {

                        let imageObjects = objects as? [NSData?]


                        let image = UIImage(data:objects!)

                        self.userImageView.image = image
                        print(image)
                    }}}

        }
        else{
            print("Error in retrieving \(error)")
        }

    }//findObjectsInBackgroundWithblock - end


     }
```

am trying to retrieve an image which is stored in parse.com's server but i don't know why am getting an error , and am not sure that my approach  for getting the image is right or not so please help me if any body knows how to do it rightly or what am missing or doing wrong the error am getting is

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Your approach seems good to me. Maybe your could add some prints or breakpoints so that you know where it breaks. Also, you could maybe try giving specific names to the results: instead of objects, you could name them imageFiles in the first and imageDatas in the second query.

Comment: which line gives you the failure?

Comment: this line     -  let thumbNail = object["image"] as! PFFile
 ,above of the thumbnail.getdata..... @Polis

Comment: okay lets see @QuentinMalgaud

Comment: also, make sure "image" is the name of the instance on the Parse server. Make sure it is not something like "Image" or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think that the only reason you get a nil result is because you are using an incorrect column name, i.e. "image". Are you sure this is the exact naming of your column in Parse?

Once you're past that error, you should be able to get the image to load fine since your code seems OK. You could however also consider PFImageView and save yourself the trouble of the extra coding since you can specify a PFFile object to the its *file* property. See [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/pfimageview-takes-a-pffile-that-it-will-download-how-do-i-get-that-pfile) for an example.

Comment: hey @polis that was my dumbness you're right hahaha the name of column was different hahhahha but thanks i really appreciate this have a good day